# How to change the value output of a autocomplete into the label output in jquery?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, label, inputbox

I'm starting to learn jQuery. But I can't find the solution to this "simple" problem?
When I choose a "label" in my autocomplete inputbox, it eventually displays the "value".
But I want the "label" to stay in that input box and the "value" I want to put in a hidden inputbox. This is my code for autocomplete for the moment:

```
$("#input_autocomplete").autocomplete({
minLength: 2,
source: availableTags,
change: function(e, ui) {
    if (!ui.item) {
        $(this).val("");
    }
},
response: function(e, ui) {
    if (ui.content.length == 0) {
        $(this).val("");
    }
}
}).on("keydown", function(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    $(this).val("");
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To do what you require you can retain the array of `label`/`value` objects used to populate a jQueryUI Autocomplete, but `map()` it to a flat array of just the `label` contents. This avoids the value being set when an items is selected.

Then when an item is selected you can use `filter()` to lookup that value in the original array to find its value. Then you can manually update the form control with that.

Try this example:

```js
let availableTags = [{ label: "Foo", value: 1 }, { label: "FooBar", value: 2 }, { label: "Bar", value: 3 }, { label: "BarFoo", value: 4 }]
let $hiddenValue = $('#hidden-value');

$("#input_autocomplete").autocomplete({
  minLength: 2,
  source: availableTags.map(t => t.label),
  select: function(e, ui) {
    let id = availableTags.filter(tag => tag.label === ui.item.label)[0].value;
    $hiddenValue.val(id);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<input type="text" id="input_autocomplete">
<input type="text" id="hidden-value" readonly />
```

Comment: Thank u so much Rory, this helps me allot! i was breaking my head over this for days ;)

Comment: No problem. If the answer helped, don't forget to accept it by clicking the green tick to the left